# Laravel @extends and @include

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on this project using Laravel.

According to this tutorial I'm watching, I had to add this bit of code at the top of the main view.

```
 @extends('layouts.masters.main')
```

Since I'm new to Laravel this got me wondering why can i not simply use.

```
   @include('layouts.masters.main')
```

I tried it instead and it did the same thing basically. Only thing is i do know how include works but i don't really know what extends does.
Is there a difference and so yeah what is it. Why did tutorial guy go for `@extends` and not  `@include.`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`@include` is just like a basic PHP include, it includes a "partial" view into your view.

`@extends` lets you "extend" a template, which defines its own sections etc. A template that you can extend will define its own sections using `@yield`, which you can then put your own stuff into in your view file.

Example:

**template.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
        @yield('header')
        @yield('content')
        @yield('footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

**view-one.blade.php**

```
@extends('template')

@section('header')
    View one's header
@endsection

@section('content')
    View one's content
@endsection

@section('footer')
    View one's footer
@endsection
```

Which will result in:

```
<html>
    <body>
        View one's header
        View one's content
        View one's footer
    </body>
</html>
```

Now you could create another view which extends the same template, but provides its own sections.

Another benefit to using `@extend` is inheritance. You could provide a base template, and then another child template that extends that one which subsequently yields it's own sections. You can then extend that child template.

Comment: what we should use if we have to include header scripts or css files..should we still use extends in layout master ?

Comment: @RahulSharma I would still use `@extends`. You can define a section by using `@yield('something')` and then you can insert your own `<script>` or `<link>` (Or whatever else) tags into that section using `@section('something')`

Comment: So, if I am using `@include`, the `@section` will not working, right?

Answer (score 12):

`@include` does not provide the structural skeleton that extending a layout template with @extend does.  With `@include` you're inserting a partial from another file.

extending a blade template provides a structure to the view that is defined in the layout template. For example, the layout:

**layouts/layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>  <meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>DOCUMENT</title></head>
  <body>
    @yield('header')
    @yield('content_1')
    @yield('content_2')
    @yield('content_3')
    @yield('footer')
  </body>
</html>
```

with the view

**show.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content_1')
    <h2>Content1 Puppy Dog</h2>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <h1>I wanna be at the bottom</h1>
@endsection

@section ('content_3')
    <h2>Content3 Horsie</h2>
@endsection

@section ('content_2')
    <h2>Content2 Kitty Cat</h2>
@endsection

@section('header')
    <h1>I wanna be at the top</h1>
@endsection
```

Gives the output:

```
<body>
<h1>I wanna be at the top</h1>
<h2>Content1 Puppy Dog</h2>
<h2>Content2 Kitty Cat</h2>
<h2>Content3 Horsie</h2>
<h1>I wanna be at the bottom</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: How was this different to the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

`@extends` with `@section` is more powerful and convenient way to use layout(s), especially in larger apps. It allows to use inheritance. You can do the same with multiple `@include` but it will be less readable and less maintainable solution.

Read more about `@extends` and how it works [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-a-layout).