# What is the difference between Laravel @extends and @include

Tags: php, laravel

I'am new to Laravel I just want to know the difference between  `@extends` and `@include`

```
@extends('tempalate')
```

can I use `@include` to add template file in my laravel project.

```
@include('tempalate')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel @extends and @include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749683/laravel-extends-and-include)

Comment: yes got it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To simply put it:

Using `@include('')` function you are including or adding an existing file.

Using `@extends('')` your are sending a portion of your file to the extended file.
Which is usually wrapped inside a `@section('')` function.

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel Documentation:

> Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from
>   within another view. All variables that are available to the parent
>   view will be made available to the included view:

```
<div>
    @include('shared.errors')

    <form>
        <!-- Form Contents -->
    </form>
</div>
```

> When defining a child view, use the Blade @extends directive to
>   specify which layout the child view should "inherit". Views which
>   extend a Blade layout may inject content into the layout's sections
>   using @section directives. Remember, as seen in the example above, the
>   contents of these sections will be displayed in the layout using
>   @yield:

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/child.blade.php -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

[Laravel -> Blade Templates -> Including Subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#including-subviews)