# Trouble understanding CI4 layouts or layouts in general

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'd like to know what is the difference, if any, in inserting layouts via `extending` a view and `including` a view. Maybe I'll explain myself better with an example:
Let's say I want to insert a *sidebar* in some of my views, what I am doing rigth now is inserting the view as a partial, so I have a partial named `sidebar.php` where all the HTML for the sidebar is, now in any view I want the sidebar I jus type `<?= $this->include('partials/sidebar') ?>` and works just fine.

Now other way of displaying the same outcome would be having the sidebar as some *"content"* and then displaying it using the `section` method, so now my `sidebar.php` needs to extend via `<?= $this->extend('layouts/main1') ?>`, have the HTML as part of the `<?= $this->section('content') ?>` and then on my layout I just render it with `<?= $this->renderSection('content') ?>`. Doing so produces the same result as the previous example.

As I said in the title I am using CodeIgniter 4 framework for my MVC, what are the advantages of doing one method over the other, is it the same? Maybe there's just some use cases that I am not considering...

Comment: I found this rather nice explanation of includes and extends:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749683/laravel-extends-and-include