# Laravel extends function: Extends not displayed in div

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel8 and want to extend another view in my home view.
I create a new div, when I run it in the browser, the extend not display properly. I test by adding heading 1, heading 1 in the top, then the extend in the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    .header {
        background-color: aquamarine;
        height: 100px;
    }

    h5 {
        height: 50px;
    }

    .main {
        background-color: beige;
        height: 600px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }




    .footer {
        background-color: #bdf7f1;
        height: 80px;
    }


    .slideleft {
        /* position: fixed; */
        width: 200px;
        top: 100;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 80;
        height: 600px;
        background-color: #f5bdf7;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .slideleft tbody {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;

    }

    .header h5 {
        float: right;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .center {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 50px;
    }

</style>


@livewireStyles
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img width="100" src="shorturl.at/irNPS"
            alt="">
    </div>
    <div>

        <h5>Addres Book</h5>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="main">


    <div class="slideleft">
        <div class="upper">
            <a href="{{ route('addstudents') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="text-align: center;">
                <button>Add New Contact</button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <tbody>
            @if ($students->count() > 0)
                @foreach ($students as $student)
                    <tr>
                        {{-- <a href=" "></a> --}}
                        <a href="{{ route ('editstudents', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" wire:click="$emit('showedit')" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                            style="padding: 1px 8px;">
                            <td>{{ $student->name }}</td>
                        </a>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center;">No students found!</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        </tbody>

    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <h1>check</h1>
        @extends('livewire.crud.add-student-component')
        {{-- @section('check')
        
            @endsection --}}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>

@livewireScripts
```

[image: this image was describe that h1 in top, then extend in the buttom]

I was an edit to configure the style, but still not working. Is the width from another view too large that causing the view display at the bottom.
how can I write properly that all my div display well?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an @include instead of the @extends.

Look here: [Laravel @extends and @include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749683/laravel-extends-and-include)

Comment: I learn that in Laravel using extends. I think extends in the same way that I include other views. So is it different?

Comment: I was editing with Include, and it's work, so what the function extends?